# 1 Interface with 2 IP's. How can I make UFW or Firewall-Cmd make different rulesets per IP

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw, firewalld, nftables

So I have a server with 1 interface "Eth0" and that interface has 2 IP's

```
192.168.0.10 -> Apache2
192.168.0.20 -> NginX
```

They share the same default gateway.

How can I make Firewall rules for each individual IP?

Comment: Have you read the manual of `ufw`? What have you tried?

Comment: Use iptables or nftables directly. Its easier to undestand then ufw or firewalld bullshit

Answer (score 0):

You don't need configure firewall to do this. You need edit configs your web-servers to tell them which ip they should listen.

For apache2 edit `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` like this:

```
Listen 192.168.0.10:80
```

For nginx edit `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` or other file with `server { }` like this:

```
server {
        listen 192.168.0.20:80 default_server;
```

Then restart your web-servers:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```

Now you can check which ip listen by each server:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 80
sudo ss -tulpn | grep 80
```